# Code injection in a MFC application

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a Win32 application that gets the HANDLE of a MFC application. My goal is to force the MFC program not to display ASSERT error message box.

Basically, I have made a prototype that allows my Win32 application to force the MFC application to show a message box, just to check if the idea is possible. Now I need to force the MFC application not to display such ASSERT error message boxes.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just get the source of the application and fix it. :-)  I guess you could open the executable in OllyDbg, find the alert dialog text so you can see which instructions refer to it and NOP them out (either by modifying the executable or by patching them after attaching to the process).

Comment: Or you can disable every MessageBox call just replacing a reference to message box show function in the import table with your own function. This can be automated

Comment: @dvvrd Your solution sounds promising, do you mean in my Win32 code I can call a function that will replace that show function called by the MFC application?

Comment: Yeap, you just need to parse your MFC app PE file, find import table there and replace it with your wanted address. I used to write something like this, if you want I can post code here

Comment: @dvvrd: I like see your code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by intercepting the `MessageBoxA`/`MessageBoxW` function call. At a usermode level, this is typically done in one of three places:

- **Call site** - There may be more than one call to `MessageBox` in your executable. You need to find the one that you want to disable. Then you can overwrite the call with code that does nothing (i.e. overwrite with `nop` instructions).
- **IAT** - The Import Address Table; a table of function pointers filled in by the PE loader. Execution often (but not always) flows through here and replacing the function pointer for `MessageBox` can allow the `MessageBox` call to be redirected to some routine that does nothing.
- **Function entry point** - The start of the `MessageBox` function. This can be located by `GetProcAddress` and the first instruction replaced with a `ret`.

The manipulation is done either at runtime (dynamically) or statically (binary rewriting/executable editing) with the first option being far more common. A library which can help you achieve runtime detouring is Microsoft Detours.

This is not a comprehensive list of all the possibilities, but rather the most common methods of execution redirection and detouring.

Answer (score 1):

To my great regret I missed that code. However you still can do it by hands.

1. Download and install [CFF explorer](http://download.cnet.com/CFF-Explorer/3000-2383_4-10431156.html)
2. Open your exe-file with it
3. Select import directory in sections explorer.
4. Select USER32.dll in the imported dll list
5. Select MessageBoxA or MessageBoxW. Edit OFT column. Write there OFT of some "harmless" function. I used GetWindowRect as example.

[image]

If you still want an appliaction to do this, I have a code with very similar functionality. It just embeds your dll into import table. You may both edit it to reach wanted result or to use it to redirect MessageBoxW call to your handler.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD MapFile(HANDLE &FileMapping, LPVOID &FileBegin, const _TCHAR *exeName) {
    HANDLE File = CreateFile(exeName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                                    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (File == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        return GetLastError();
    }   

    FileMapping = CreateFileMapping(File, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(File);

    if (!FileMapping) {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    FileBegin = MapViewOfFile(FileMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    if (!FileBegin) {
        CloseHandle(FileMapping);
        return GetLastError();
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD RewriteImportTable(const HANDLE FileMapping, const LPVOID FileBegin, const _TCHAR *dllName, const _TCHAR *funcName, DWORD &finalResult) {

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* dos_header;
    IMAGE_FILE_HEADER* file_header;
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER* optional_header;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* section_header;

    // Counting PE-header offset
    dos_header = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*) FileBegin;
    DWORD PEOffset = dos_header->e_lfanew;
    file_header = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER*) ((DWORD)FileBegin + PEOffset); // file_header must reference "PE\0"

    // Checking if we work with PE
    _TCHAR* PEString = "PE\0";
    if (_tcscmp(PEString, (const _TCHAR*) file_header) != 0) {
        printf("This file is not Portable Executable!\n");
        return 666;
    }

    file_header = (IMAGE_FILE_HEADER *)((DWORD)file_header + sizeof(DWORD)); // Ignoring PE
    optional_header = (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER *)((DWORD)file_header + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER));

    // Finding import section
    DWORD ImportRVA = optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
    int sectNum = -1;

    // Finding import table
    section_header = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*) ((DWORD) optional_header + sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER));

    for (int i = 0; i < (file_header->NumberOfSections); i++) {
        if (ImportRVA < (section_header->VirtualAddress)) {
            section_header--;
            sectNum = i-1;
            break;  
        }
        section_header++;
    }

    if (sectNum == -1) {
        printf("This program uses no external libraries! (strange)\n");
        return 666;
    }

    // Getting address of section folowing import section
    section_header++;
    DWORD SectionNextToImportBegin = (DWORD)FileBegin + section_header->PointerToRawData;
    section_header--;

    // Getting the address of the import table
    LPVOID ImportSectionBegin = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)FileBegin + section_header->PointerToRawData);

    // Counting the import table offset in the import section
    LPVOID ImportTable = (LPVOID)((DWORD)ImportSectionBegin + (ImportRVA - section_header->VirtualAddress));

    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR *DLLInfo = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*) ImportTable;
    LPVOID DLLName;
    DWORD DLLCounter = 0;

    while (DLLInfo->Name != NULL) {
        DLLCounter++;
        DLLName = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)ImportSectionBegin + ((DWORD)DLLInfo->Name - section_header->VirtualAddress));
        DLLInfo++;
    }

    printf("Number of imported libraries: %d\n", DLLCounter);

    // Counting the size of the future import table
    DWORD newImportTableSize = sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) * (DLLCounter + 2);

    // Finding the end of the import section
    LPVOID pos = (LPVOID) (SectionNextToImportBegin - 1);

    DWORD maxFree = 0;
    DWORD prevPtr;
    LPVOID freePtr = NULL;

    // Searching for the free place
    while (pos >= ImportSectionBegin) {
        if (*(BYTE*)pos == 0) {
            prevPtr = (DWORD) pos;

            while (*(BYTE*)pos == 0) {
                pos = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)pos - 1);
            }

            if (((DWORD)prevPtr - (DWORD)pos) > maxFree) {
                maxFree = ((DWORD)prevPtr - (DWORD)pos);
                freePtr = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)pos + 1);
            }
        }
        pos = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)pos - 1);
    }

    // Modifying pointer: it can refer the tailing zero of some stucture
    freePtr = (LPVOID) ((LPDWORD)freePtr + 1);
    maxFree -= 4;

    // Checking if we have enough space in the import section
    if (maxFree < newImportTableSize) {
        printf("Not enough free space in Import Section\n");
        return 666;
    }

    printf("Injecting new library...\n");

    // Copying old import table on the new place
    memcpy(freePtr, ImportTable, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) * DLLCounter);

    // Saving everithing we need on the old place
    typedef struct {
        DWORD ZeroDword;
        DWORD IAT;
        DWORD IATEnd;
    } MeanStruct;

    MeanStruct patch;
    patch.ZeroDword = NULL; // this is \0 for dll name
    patch.IAT = ImportRVA + _tcslen(dllName) + sizeof(MeanStruct); // RVA to where list of functions begins
    patch.IATEnd = NULL;

    WORD Hint = 0;

    IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME myName;
    myName.Hint = 0x00;
    myName.Name[0] = 0x00;

    LPDWORD zeroPtr = (LPDWORD) ImportTable;
    memcpy(zeroPtr, dllName, _tcslen(dllName));
    zeroPtr = (LPDWORD) ((DWORD)zeroPtr + strlen(dllName));
    memcpy(zeroPtr, &patch, sizeof(patch));
    zeroPtr = (LPDWORD) ((DWORD)zeroPtr + sizeof(patch));

    finalResult = (DWORD)zeroPtr - (DWORD)ImportSectionBegin + section_header->VirtualAddress;

    memcpy(zeroPtr, &Hint, sizeof(WORD));
    zeroPtr = (LPDWORD) ((DWORD)zeroPtr + sizeof(WORD));
    memcpy(zeroPtr, funcName, strlen(funcName) + 1); // we have no need to write \0 into the end - this is already free space
    zeroPtr = (LPDWORD) ((DWORD)zeroPtr + strlen(funcName) + 1);
    memcpy(zeroPtr, &myName, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME));

    // filling info about dll
    IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR myDLL;

    // counting RVA for IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME: 
    DWORD IIBN_Table = ImportRVA + strlen(dllName) + sizeof(DWORD);

    // function name pointer
    myDLL.Characteristics = IIBN_Table;
    myDLL.TimeDateStamp = NULL;
    myDLL.ForwarderChain = NULL;
    // dll name pointer
    myDLL.Name = ImportRVA;
    myDLL.FirstThunk = IIBN_Table;

    // writting dll info into the new import table
    LPVOID oldFreePtr = freePtr;
    freePtr = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)freePtr + sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) * DLLCounter);
    memcpy(freePtr, &myDLL, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));

    // creating list tail
    myDLL.Characteristics = NULL;
    myDLL.TimeDateStamp = NULL;
    myDLL.ForwarderChain = NULL;
    myDLL.Name = NULL;
    myDLL.FirstThunk = NULL;

    // writing list tail
    freePtr = (LPVOID) ((DWORD)freePtr + sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));
    memcpy(freePtr, &myDLL, sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR));

    // setting new import table rva
    DWORD newImportTableRVA = (DWORD)oldFreePtr - (DWORD)ImportSectionBegin + section_header->VirtualAddress;

    // changing DataDirectory
    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress = newImportTableRVA;
    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size = (DLLCounter + 1) * sizeof(IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR);

    // clearing non-actual values
    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT].VirtualAddress = 0;
    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BOUND_IMPORT].Size = 0;

    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].VirtualAddress = 0;
    optional_header->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IAT].Size = 0;

    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Invalid arguments number!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    HANDLE FileMapping;
    LPVOID FileBegin;
    DWORD FileMappingResult = MapFile(FileMapping, FileBegin, argv[1]);
    if (0 != FileMappingResult) {
        printf("Error of file mapping (%d)\n", FileMappingResult);
        if (NULL != FileMapping) CloseHandle(FileMapping);
        return FileMappingResult;
    }

    DWORD functionAddr;
    DWORD RewriteImportTableResult = RewriteImportTable(FileMapping, FileBegin, argv[2], argv[3], functionAddr);
    if (0 != RewriteImportTableResult) {
        UnmapViewOfFile(FileBegin);
        CloseHandle(FileMapping);
        return 666;
    }

    printf("Library successfully injected!\n");
    printf("Address of injected function: %X", functionAddr);

    UnmapViewOfFile(FileBegin);
    CloseHandle(FileMapping);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that not all calls will go through the IAT. For example, if the address is found dynamically through `GetProcAddress`

Comment: @Mike Kwan: Very good note, but the goal is to disable assertation message boxes. Their calls will go through th IAT